# ERROR: syntax error at or near ";" LINE 28: END;

Tags: postgresql, trigger, function

Actualmente me veo en la necesidad de crear un trigger function para mi sistema pero me esta arrojando un error y debido a mi poca experiencia con este tipo de funciones no logro identificar el problema, a continuación las evidencias:

**Trigger Function:**

```html
 -- here start procedural part
DECLARE _user_id bigint;
DECLARE owner_id bigint;

BEGIN

    _user_id = NEW.user_id;

    SELECT owner into owner_id FROM owners_belongs WHERE belong = _user_id LIMIT 1;
                        
    IF FOUND THEN
                        
        UPDATE currentservices
        SET total_sents = total_sents + 1 WHERE user_id = owner_id AND is_active = true;
                            
     ELSE
                        
        UPDATE currentservices
        SET total_sents = total_sents + 1 WHERE user_id = _user_id AND is_active = true;
                        
    RETURN null;

END;
```

**El código de error:**

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 28: END;
```

Answer (score 0):

El error lo tenia porque no había cerrado el `IF`, debía colocar `END IF` para terminar la secuencia de validaciones